# Join 3 tables into 1 larger table SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables and they all have the column date.

t1.date | t1.id, t2.date | t2.id, t3.date| t3.id

and I want to join them together into a larger table with only one date column like

date | t1.id | t2.id | t3.id

Is it possible and how to do that?
Do I need to create a new table with t1,t2,t3 as foreign keys?

For example, inputs:

```
t1.date     | t1.id       t2.date    | t2.id      t3.date    | t3.id
2020-01-01  |   1         2020-05-01 |   2        2020-03-01 |   3
```

Output:

```
Date        |   t1.d    |   t2.id   |   t3.id
2020-01-01  |   1       |   null    |   null
2020-03-01  |   null    |   null    |   3
2020-05-01  |   null    |   2       |   null
```

Comment: Suppose that for a given date, say 2020-12-11, each of the tables `t1`, `t2` and `t3` contained information.  Would there be one output row (`2020-12-11`, `value from t1`, `value from t2`, `value from t3`), or would there be three rows with each row containing one value and the same date?  What would happen if there were three rows in `t1` for some date, say `2020-12-10`, and four rows in `t2` for the same date, and five rows in `t3` for the same date?  What should the output look like then?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed create a table that references `"t1"`, `"t2"` and `"t3"`.

Here is the **SQL** for that table:

```
CREATE TABLE "table_name"(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  single_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  t1_id INT, -- Replace it with the type from your reference table (Might be UUID)
  t2_id INT,
  t3_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT table_name_t1_fkey FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES "t1" (id),
  CONSTRAINT table_name_t2_fkey FOREIGN KEY (t2_id) REFERENCES "t2" (id),
  CONSTRAINT table_name_t3_fkey FOREIGN KEY (t3_id) REFERENCES "t3" (id)
);
```

Now you can import the data from your other tables like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (t1_id, single_date)
(SELECT id, date FROM t1)

INSERT INTO table_name (t2_id, single_date)
(SELECT id, date FROM t2)

INSERT INTO table_name (t3_id, single_date)
(SELECT id, date FROM t3)
```

Comment: thank you! but can I insert the  date from t1, t2 and t3 into "single_date"?

Comment: Good question. I have edited my answer to include the insert statements.